# How to fix the domain issue while using the active directory library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to run a python query to find_user in all the AD and domains.
But this script is only working for EU domain as the script is currently running on an EU server. Can someone help on how do i re frame the query to check the other domain users as well?

I am using active directory library for the same to fetch the user details in the script.

```
def find_user(user_id):
    logger.debug('Begin find_user with %s' % user_id)
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    try:
        user = active_directory.find_user(user_id)
        if user is not None:
            muid = user.employeeID
            username = user.displayName
            user_dict = {'uid': user_id, 'muid': muid, 'displayName': username, 'member_of': user.memberOf}
            logger.debug('display username %s ' % user_dict)
            member_of = user.memberOf
            logger.debug('member_of: %s' % member_of)
            for gr in member_of:
                logger.warn('%s is in Group: %s' % (muid, gr))
                #print('%s is in Group: %s' % (muid, gr))
            return user_dict
        else:
            logger.error('No AD information for %s' % user_id)
            raise NoADInformationError('No AD information for %s' % user_id)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Active Directory User not fetched %s' % user_id)
        active_directory._CACHE = {}
        active_directory._connection = None
        raise NoADInformationError('No AD information for %s ;Exception %s' % (user_id, e))
```

Comment: If all of your Active Directory domains are part of a single Active Directory forest, then you can search the Global Catalog (on ports 3268 and 3269 instead of 389/636  respectively).  The GC contains a subset of attributes for all users in the Forest.

Comment: how do i add the criteria in this code?

Comment: You really want to be using PowerShell for this.  I'm sure Python is great for lots of things but the lack of examples of Python/AD stuff suggests this isn't one of them.  Assuming you don't want to go down that route, I was looking at the [Active Directory Cookbook](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/ad_cookbook.html) and [active_directory](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/active_directory.html) and wondering if you can do this: `me = active_directory.AD_object ("LDAP://dc=your,dc=local,dc=domain")`  and then `me.find_user(user_id)`.  If that works, then try `"GC://dc=root,dc=domain"`.

Comment: i.e. first get this kind of search working for your current domain, just like you have it now but with you specifying the search root.  Then try getting it working with the Global Catalog.